# Cassandra 3.11 SSTableLoader mechanics

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, scylla

I've been using the SSTableLoader utility to bulk transfer data between two distinct Cassandra clusters and I was wondering if anyone else has run into the same issues.  The source cluster has data, the destination does not.

I've read the datastax page on the utility's details but still I have some unanswered questions about how it works.

I am using the utility on the source cluster's live nodes and the commands follow this format:

```
sstableloader -d target.host.ip -v -f /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml /cassandra/data/keyspace1/table1-uuid
```

The clusters are both setup with 256 vnodes each with 6 nodes in each cluster.  The schema is RF = 3 in both environments and the tables are all structured the same.

So my questions are as follows:

1) The utility pulls source cluster information from the cassandra.yaml you specify, but you have to specify an absolute path to the SSTables still.  So does running SSTableLoader from a single node give me the entire table at the destination once complete?  It seems difficult to verify since the token ranges are different at the destination cluster.

2) The datastax information says:

> To get the best throughput from SSTable loading, you can use multiple
>   instances of sstableloader to stream across multiple machines. No hard
>   limit exists on the number of SSTables that sstableloader can run at
>   the same time, so you can add additional loaders until you see no
>   further improvement.

Does this mean that for a single table, I would start multiple instances of SSTableLoader across multiple source machines?  Or does it just mean that I can use SSTableLoader for multiple different tables on multiple machines at the same time.  I'm trying to understand if the throughput gain they are mentioning is for a single table or for just multiple tables in flight.

3) What syntax modification is needed to run from snapshots instead?  I took a snapshot and tested by running the same command but further down into the snapshot directory of the table and it didn't parse correctly it was saying "snapshot" is an invalid keyspace.

Anyway thanks hope I was clear enough with my questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) If your RF=3 and your cluster had 3 nodes, than each node holds **ALL** the data. Still there could be some minor changes due to updates that did not propagate to all replicas yet. If the number of nodes in your cluster is bigger than the RF (you your case 6 nodes, RF=3), than every node holds a combination of 50% of the data (different token ranges).
Anyhow, you need to run the `sstableloader` on all keyspaces + tables from each of your source nodes to the new cluster's destination nodes (assuming 1:1 ratio).

2) Yes, you can run multiple sstableloaders on the same table / keyspace from each of the source nodes, to it's matching destination node in parallel. But it also means you can do it for different keyspace / tables, as long as eventually you performed it from all source nodes for all keyspace / tables to their matching destination nodes (assuming 1:1 ratio).

3) Restoring from Backup (Snapshot) is a different procedure which does not involve using `sstableloader`. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/procedures/restore/).

There is also an option to use `nodetool refresh` to load sstables from all source nodes to the new destination nodes, but it should be used only when the num_nodes=RF. Read more about it [here](https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/nodetool-commands/refresh/)

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense.  In addition, do you know what format the -d arguments have to be in to specify multiple target host ips?  I tried a simple list of ip,ip,ip with commas and it did not accept that.   The datastax docs aren't more specific than that though... sstableloader -d host_url (,host_url …) [options] path_to_keyspace

Comment: the `sstableloader` should run from 1 source node to 1 target node. If you want to run multiple instances it will have to be multiple processes of `sstableloader`, from the same source node each one for different table to a different single target node.

Comment: Ok last question, is there some formula or way to determine the minimum number of nodes you need to run on?  At cluster size 6 and RF = 3 as you said, that is 50% of the data on each node.  Wouldn't running it on 3 guarantee getting atleast 1/3 replicas?  And from there you would repair on the target cluster?  Asking for the sake of speed of doing this.  Especially if your cluster become larger than like 20 nodes

Comment: I don't understand your statement of "running it on 3" - 3 what? 3 nodes with RF=3, than each node holds all data. For production you need a minimum 3 nodes in a cluster. If I did not understand, please clarify.

Comment: I meant on 3 nodes out of a total cluster size of 6 with RF = 3.  For example, if I run SSTableLoader from 5 out of 6 nodes I would expect there to be a full data set on the target cluster, but with some replica repairs needed.  My question then is what is the minimum I can do and what formula can you use to calculate that minimum for other cluster configurations?

Comment: Few assumptions here:

1. Data in source cluster is fully synced - full repair, before you start migrating to the destination cluster, and no new writes.
2. Assuming item-1 is OK: you can do num_nodes_in_cluster - (RF-X=1). e.g. for 6-nodes cluster, RF=3, you should be OK by running it from 4 nodes.
3. sstableloader runs with CL (consistency level) ONE by default, so having more sstableloaders than minimum, is another redundancy fails-safe mechanism.
4. In multi-DC setup, if DC-2 is a copy of DC-1, than no need to run sstableloader from dc-2 at all (assuming DCs are fully synced).

Comment: Thanks so much @TomerSan your insight has been very helpful

Comment: @RazzleDazzle  I would appreciate if you could mark this question as "Answered" by me. Thank you and good luck!